# Problem In sending signals from my Linux kernel module to user space application

Tags: c, linux-kernel, signals, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I am using an embedded board with a Linux operating system.

This board has a push button and Led.

- Button file path is : */dev/input/event0* , and has a code **260** .
- Led file Path is : */sys/class/leds* .

I want to control Led, switch on and off, through the button. Besides, I want to use signals to notify about Pushing button event occurring. The signal will be sent to user space when the event has occurred.

For that, I developed Linux kernel loadable module and principal user space application.

This is the module :

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <asm/siginfo.h>    //siginfo
#include <linux/rcupdate.h>    //rcu_read_lock
#include <linux/sched/signal.h>    //find_task_by_pid_type
#include <linux/debugfs.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>
#include <linux/input.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/fs.h> 


#define SIG_TEST 44    // we choose 44 as our signal number (real-time signals are in the range of 33 to 64)
#define BTN_FILE_PATH "/dev/input/event0"


char *str = BTN_FILE_PATH;
int file;

struct file *f;


static ssize_t write_pid(struct file *pfile, const char __user *buffer,
                                size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{
    return 0;
}



static ssize_t read_pid(struct file *pfile, char __user *buffer,
                                size_t length, loff_t *offset)
{


     char mybuf[10];
    enum { MAX_BUF_SIZE = 4096 };
    size_t buf_size = 0;
    char *buf = NULL;
    ssize_t total = 0;
    ssize_t rc = 0;
    struct task_struct *t;
    struct input_event  *ev;
    int yalv;

    int ret;
    struct siginfo info;
    int pid =0; 

    /* Allocate temporary buffer. */
    if (length) {
        buf_size = min_t(size_t, MAX_BUF_SIZE, length);
        ev = kmalloc(buf_size, GFP_KERNEL);
        if (ev == NULL) {
            return -ENOMEM;
        }
    }

    /* read the value from user space */
    if(length > 10)
        return -EINVAL;
    copy_from_user(mybuf, buffer, length);
    sscanf(mybuf, "%d", &pid);
    printk("pid = %d\n", pid);

    rcu_read_lock();
    t = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);  //find the task_struct associated with this pid
    if(t == NULL){
        printk("no such pid\n");
        rcu_read_unlock();
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    rcu_read_unlock();

 /* Read file to buffer in chunks. */

        size_t amount = min_t(size_t, length, buf_size);

        rc = kernel_read(f, ev, amount, offset);
        if (rc > 0) {
            /* Have read some data from file. */
            if (copy_to_user(buffer, ev, rc) != 0) {
                /* Bad user memory! */
                rc = -EFAULT;
            } else {
                /* Update totals. */
                total += rc;
                buffer += rc;
                *offset += rc;
                length -= rc;

        for (yalv = 0; yalv < (int) (rc / sizeof(struct input_event)); yalv++) {
            if (ev[yalv].type == EV_KEY) {
                printk("signal was send\n");
                if (ev[yalv].value == 0)
                     ret = send_sig_info(SIG_TEST, &info, t);    //send the signal
                         if (ret < 0) {
                            printk("error sending signal\n");
                        kfree(buf);
                            return ret;
                         }

            }
        }
                if (rc < amount) {
                    /* Didn't read the full amount, so terminate early. */
                    rc = 0;
                }
            }

    } 


    /* Free temporary buffer. */

    kfree(buf);

}


static const struct file_operations my_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .write = write_pid,
    .read = read_pid,
};

static int __init signalexample_module_init(void)
{

    /* we need to know the PID of the user space process
      * -> we use debugfs for this. As soon as a pid is written to 
      * this file, a signal is sent to that pid
      */
    /* only root can write to this file (no read) */
    register_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv", &my_fops);
    file = debugfs_create_file("signalconfpid", 0200, NULL, NULL, &my_fops);
    f = filp_open(str, 0 , O_RDONLY);

    return 0;
}
static void __exit signalexample_module_exit(void)
{
    unregister_chrdev(240, "Simple Char Drv");
    debugfs_remove(file);

}
```

This is the principal user-space application :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <linux/input.h>

#define BTN_FILE_PATH "/dev/input/event0"
#define LED_PATH "/sys/class/leds"
#define red "red"
#define SIG_TEST 44
#define BUFFER_LENGTH 256

void change_led_state(char *led_path, int led_value)
{
    char    lpath[64];
    FILE    *led_fd;

    strncpy(lpath, led_path, sizeof(lpath) - 1);
    lpath[sizeof(lpath) - 1] = '\0';

    led_fd = fopen(lpath, "w");

    if (led_fd == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "simplekey: unable to access led\n");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(led_fd, "%d\n", led_value);

    fclose(led_fd);
}

void reset_leds(void)
{
    change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" red "/brightness", 0);
}

int configure_leds(void)
{
    FILE    *r_fd;
    char    *none_str = "none";

    /* Configure leds for hand control */
    l_fd = fopen(LED_PATH "/" red "/trigger", "w");

    if ( r_fd == NULL) {
        perror("simplekey: unable to configure led");
        return -EACCES;
    }

    fprintf(r_fd, "%s\n", none_str);

    fclose(r_fd);

    /* Switch off leds */
    reset_leds();

    return 0;
}

void eval_keycode(int code)
{
    static int red_state = 0;

    switch (code) {
    case 260:
        printf("BTN left pressed\n");

        /* figure out red state */
        red_state = red_state ? 0 : 1;

        change_led_state(LED_PATH "/" red "/brightness", red_state);
        break;

    }
}


void receiveData(int n, siginfo_t *info, void *unused) 
{
    printf("received value %i\n", info->si_int);   
}

int main ( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int ret;
    int nc;
    int fd;
    int configfd;
    char buf[10];
    char buffer[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    /* setup the signal handler for SIG_TEST 
      * SA_SIGINFO -> we want the signal handler function with 3 arguments
      */
    struct sigaction sig;
    sig.sa_sigaction = receiveData;
    sig.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    sigaction(SIG_TEST, &sig, NULL);

    fd = open("/dev/char_device", O_RDONLY);             // Open the device with read access   
    if (fd < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to open the device...");
            return errno;
    }
     sprintf(buffer, "%i", getpid());   
    nc = read(fd,buffer,strlen(buffer));
    if (nc < 0)
    {
            perror("Failed to read the message from the device.");
            return errno;
    }

    ret = configure_leds();
    if (ret < 0)
    exit(1);

    reset_leds();
    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

After inserting the module and running the application, this returns to me only the **PID** of my user code, but when I push the button, nothing happens. The signal is not sent as I guess.

If anyone would help me, I will be grateful. Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use signals to notify about an input hardware event for a push button in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58690083/use-signals-to-notify-about-an-input-hardware-event-for-a-push-button-in-c)

Comment: @AlexHoppus No it does not help

Comment: IIRC your Device Tree configures a GPIO pin as a `gpio-keys` and another GPIO pin as `gpio-leds`, and there's a *"requirement"* that these configurations cannot be modified. As long as you use these DT configurations for userspace APIs but  insist on using a loadable kernel module, then you will forced into constructing contorted, ill-advised kernel code. IOW you're trying to fit square pegs into round holes, and ignoring the idea of using round pegs. You can't reuse a DT configuration intended for a different implementation.